# What is Professor McGonagall's position?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm just reading the Harry Potter books and what is Professor McGonagall's position? I know Dumbledore is the head, but is she slightly higher than Snape or any of the others?

Answer (score 15):

### Yes, Professor McGonagall is higher than most in the [org chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_chart)

As Oak points out in comments, McGonagall is Gryffindor's Head of House:

> Professor McGonagall was head of Gryffindor House, but it hadn't stopped her from giving them a huge pile of homework the day before.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Chapter 8: "The Potions Master"</sup>

It's unclear whether or not Head of House is a higher position than a regular professor, but it does include additional duties (a certain degree of management of the Prefects and the common room, and serving as a sort of guidance counsellor for students). To the extent it *is* considered a higher position, this alone sets her higher than most other professors; all except for the Heads of the other three houses.

As well, Professor McGonagall is the [Deputy Headmistress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deputy_head_teacher) (bold is my emphasis, italic is from the text):

> *Dear Mr. Potter,*
>
> *We are pleased to inform you that you have been accepted at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. Please find enclosed a list of all necessary books and equipment.*
>
> *Term begins on September 1. We await your owl by no later than July 31.*
>
> *Yours sincerely,*
>
> *Minerva McGonagall,*
>
> ***Deputy Headmistress***
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Chapter 4: "The Keeper of the Keys"</sup>

Which sets her higher than all of the other professors. One of her additional duties is to fill in for an incapacitated Head Teacher, until a permanent replacement can be appointed; she does this in *Chamber of Secrets*, when Lucius Malfoy has had Dumbledore removed:

> "I always thought Father might be the one who got rid of Dumbledore," [Malfoy] said, not troubling to keep his voice down. "I told you he thinks Dumbledore's the worst headmaster the school's ever had. Maybe we'll get a decent headmaster now. Someone who won’t want the Chamber of Secrets closed. McGonagall won’t last long, she's only filling in..."
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* Chapter 15: "Aragog"</sup>

Comment: She's also the Head of the House of Gryffindor, which, also makes her above other teachers, even if she wasn't the deputy

Comment: Well, at least through years 1-5, Snape was Head of the House of Slytherin.

Comment: @Oak I'm not sure to what extent that would be considered a promotion, but I've added it in

Comment: I feel like the Deputy thing should go first. Very clearly puts her ahead.

Comment: I don't know why the info about all the other heads is houses is necessary. McGonagall is head of Gryffindor and Deputy Headmaster of the school - answers the question well enough. I don't see where Gryffindor's status comes into it.

Comment: @PeregrineRook it's suggested that Heads of Houses have aditional previleges in Hogwarts, such as booking the Quiditch Camp (Chamber of secrets)

Comment: Flitwick being the head of Ravenclaw can be found in the books as will. (e.g. HBP29)